# How should inconsistent treatment of suggested edits be resolved?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

I suggested [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/755882) to update [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101107/425313) for a new version of the framework. This answer contains a previously approved [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/149680) which, though it will work, is not the [preferred method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp).

Why was the first edit approved and not the second? Should the first be rolled back? Should the second be resubmitted to replace the first?

**Edit:** This isn't about my edit getting rejected, I'm ok with that. I just want to clarify the currently misleading edit to the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring tho this suggested edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/755882 I would have rejected that one as well. If you have an answer of your own, make it one. Don't try to add it to another (already accepted) answer.

Comment: @Bart, Yes, that's the one.  I did add my own answer, but my question is about why the [previous edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/149680) received the opposite treatment and how that inconsistency should be resolved.

Comment: Different people review differently. Perhaps that one was reviewed by someone particularly knowledgeable on the subject/tag and evaluated it as correct. Who knows. I in general am more cautious about edits like this and would have rejected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question's a bit of a mess:

- Deizel gave the currently accepted answer, but subsequently added another answer with a different solution.
- Both you and Asa Ayers proposed version 2 updates to Deizel's accepted answer of which his was [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/149680) and your [wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/755882).
- Both you and Asa Ayers also provided your own answers with your respective v2 solutions.

Given that your solution is a perfectly reasonable standalone answer to the question, there's no reason not to provide it independently (as you've done), perhaps adding a *comment* to the accepted answer about newer-version compatibility.  Because this is an old question, it might take a while for it to get enough eyes to bring your answer nearer the top, but hopefully anyone facing the same problem will be diligent enough to look at more than just the top answer(s).

As to Asa Ayer's edit being accepted while yours wasn't, the edit review process isn't perfect, and doesn't always produce consistent (or desirable) results. You could certainly suggest a rollback of Asa Ayer's edit, but I wouldn't be confident that it wouldn't also be rejected. A good edit description would be a must.

Answer (score 2):

> Deizel gave the currently accepted answer, but subsequently added another answer with a different solution.

I always believed my second answer was the preferred solution for CakePHP 1.3, though it was never the accepted answer. Now that we have two more similar answers - but for CakePHP 2.x this time - I do agree that this question could be tidier.

> Both you and Asa Ayers proposed version 2 updates to Deizel's accepted answer of which his was accepted and your wasn't.

I would say that it's only fair to either accept both edits or deny both edits...

> Both you and Asa Ayers also provided your own answers with your respective v2 solutions.

Since both edits have been provided as answers, I am choosing to remove Asa Ayers edit to remove duplication.

I've [added links to the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1101107/revisions) to hopefully signpost to future visitors what each answer is for.

Answer (score 0):

Both suggestions should have been rejected.  It is a serious problem that we have been having with the review queue (since pretty much forever) that too many people accept suggestions that they shouldn't.  Some seem to not properly understand what should and shouldn't be approved, some are too lazy to take all the time that is needed to determine the proper course of action and just approve almost anything, and some people just feel that there should be looser/stricter guidelines on what is approved.

There have been *lots* of discussions in meta on the subject, some of which have been implemented, but the problem remains.  There isn't much I can tell you other than to understand the guidelines yourself and try not to submit edits that shouldn't be approved (rather than relying on the reviewers to actually reject bad suggestions).

If you're just mad at the inconsistency, you're not alone.